# Name of terms before and after "=" (equal sign)?

Tags: terminology

What are name of the terms before and after equal sign?

Examples:

```
student1 = John;
height = 100.0;
hasLight = false;
```

Before: student1, height, hasLight.
After: John, 100.0, false.

I think the term after equal sign is "value" but not sure if it's correct.

Comment: Left of the assignment operator is `lvalue`. To the right are expressions is `rvalue` @MiP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're both "operands" to the assignment operator¹ (`=`).

The right-hand operand might loosely be called the "value" that's being assigned, although more accurately it's an expression and it's the expression's resulting value that gets assigned.

The left-hand operand is typically called the "target" of the assignment, sometimes the "assignee."

---

¹ I'm assuming from context that it's an assignment operator. Some languages use `=` for testing equality (e.g., `if (height = 100.0)`). If it's an equality operator rather than an assignment operator, then they're just "operands" and the other two terms above don't apply.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing an [assignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_(computer_science)):

you are giving the value 100.0 to the variable height on line 2 for example

Answer (score 0):

To the left of the assignment operator are variables. To the right are expressions, in your examples all are literal values.

Answer (score 0):

Less general terms could also be:
Variable/Constant = Value;

More names from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbkb459w.aspx):

> The assignment operator (=) stores the value of its right-hand operand in the storage location, property, or indexer denoted by its left-hand operand and returns the value as its result.